# Cleaning a Listview for data

Tags: android

I've got a ListView, an ArrayList. From activity1, I pass some data, e.g a price and a name of a company. This data will be stored in an ArrayList of Hashmaps. When I first passes some data to the second activity which holds the ListView the data will be found in this list, but when I go back to the first activity and pass some information again, the old data will still be in the list. Is there any possible way I can prevent this to happend? For instance, when I return from activity2 to activity1, the ListView will be wiped.

Thanks!

Comment: That's strange. When you go "back" to the first activity, the second activity should have been destroyed, along with any data. Except static variables. You should post the relevant code from both of your activities.

Comment: I should say that I dont have any onStart() or onDestory() methods.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

what you need to do:
on the activity which holds the listView - override the onResume() method:

```
@Override
protected void onResume() {
    super.onResume();

    mArrayList.clear();
    mAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
}
```

if it's not good for you to clear the array list, so you can do the following:

```
@Override
protected void onResume() {
    super.onResume();

    mListView.removeAllViews();
}
```

Comment: Thanks! This worked, except I had to change the method to onDestory(), else the list would not show anything.